# Cambiar color barra en highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

tengo un gráfico de [barras](https://jsfiddle.net/nachfren/La6mb345/1/), así:

[image: Gráfico barras]

Me gustaría poder cambiar el color de cada barra libremente. es decir si yo tengo los siguientes valores:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5]

}, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6, 78.8]

}, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [48.9, 38.8]

}, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [42.4, 33.2]

}]
```

Por ejemplo para el mes de Enero, para la medida de Tokyo poder cambiar el color del valor 30 al 45.

Algo parecido a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible cambiar el color un rango concreto?

Answer (score 2):

No se si esto se aproxima a lo que quieres lograr... Espero que te sirva.

En caso contrario, puedes probar con [otro tipo de gráfico](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Tokyo',
            'New York',
            'London',
            'Berlín'
          ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Range3',
        data: [20, 50, 10, 12]

    }, {
        name: 'Range2',
        data: [15, 10, 25, 35]

    }, {
        name: 'Range1',
        data: [30, 20, 45, 20]

    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Ya vi ese gráfico, pero no me vale necesito que sea uno normal y poder establecer colores por medidas.